# TinyVirtuoso: where is the documentation?

Tags: database, rdf, virtuoso, triplestore

I found this NuGet package interesting: a embedded rdf database in C# based on OpenLink Virtuoso, with MIT licensing...

But, when I tried to find any instruction about usage, or the API reference, I couldn't find it...

I installed TinyVirtuoso.win  v 7.2.1 from NuGet ...

Why doesn't the sample code in "[First Steps](https://bitbucket.org/semiodesk/tinyvirtuoso/wiki/FirstSteps)" work?

It does not recognize `VirtuosoConnection()` nor `IStore`

```
using Semiodesk.TinyVirtuoso;
using Semiodesk.VirtuosoInstrumentation;

// Create a new Virtuoso store in a directory named 'Data', located in your app folder.
var virtuoso = new TinyVirtuoso("Data");

// You can have multiple separate database instances which contain different data.
// This will create a directory "Data/ExampleProject" in your app directory.
var instance = virtuoso.GetOrCreateInstance("ExampleProject");

// Start the embedded database server instance.
instance.Start();

// a) You can access the store using the Semiodesk Trinity graph database API.
// Please refer to our Trinity documentation and examples for more information.
IStore store = StoreFactory.CreateStore(instance.GetTrinityConnectionString());

// b) Alternatively, you can use it with plain ADO.Net to use the relational
// database features and SQL (make sure to install OpenLink.Data.Virtuoso).
var connection = new VirtuosoConnection();
connection.ConnectionString = instance.GetAdoNetConnectionString();
connection.Connect();

// When you are done, stop the embedded database server instance.
instance.Stop();
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking it over quickly, I think TinyVirtuoso is not an "embedded RDF database in C#" (which is not surprising, as that would require portation of the entire C-based VOS (Virtuoso Open Source) project).  Note that [their wiki says](https://bitbucket.org/semiodesk/tinyvirtuoso#rst-header-license) —

> TinyVirtuoso does not link against OpenLink Virtuoso in any way. It just provides a way to start, stop and configure the software.

[Elsewhere in that wiki](https://bitbucket.org/semiodesk/tinyvirtuoso), they say they depend on the [Open Source Virtuoso project](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/), but it's not clear whether they fully install Virtuoso, just install the ADO.NET client library, or somewhere in between.

I did notice [this advice](https://bitbucket.org/semiodesk/tinyvirtuoso/wiki/Home) --

> The software is supported by Semiodesk. If you have any questions, suggestions or just want to tell us in which projects you are using the library, don't hesitate to hello@semiodesk.com.

-- which led me to a [somewhat more informative (and I think more recently updated) page](https://www.semiodesk.com/products/tinyvirtuoso/) on [Semiodesk's website](https://www.semiodesk.com/), which suggests that they do indeed intend bundling the main Virtuoso binary, among other things, which I don't think you've installed yet.

[Documentation of Virtuoso](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/) itself, and [its ADO.NET Provider](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/virtclientrefintro/) (both [Installation/Configuration](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/virtclientrefinstallandconfig/) and [Programming/API](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/virtclientrefprogrammersguide/)), are found on the OpenLink website.

I hope this is helpful...